# Use agg() to my dataframe, there is no result

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to calculate the median and counts of specific column of my data frame:

```
large_depts = df[df['Department'].isin(Departments_top10)]\
                    [['Total', 'Department']]\
                    .groupby('Department')\
                    .agg([np.median, np.size])
print(large_depts)
```

It said:

```
ValueError: no results
```

But when I checked the dataframe, there were values in my dataframe:

```
large_depts = df[df['Department'].isin(Departments_top10)]\
                    [['Total', 'Department']]
print(large_depts)

            Total                      Department
0      677,680.65        Boston Police Department
1      250,893.61        Boston Police Department
2      208,676.89        Boston Police Department
3      319,319.93        Boston Police Department
4      577,123.44        Boston Police Department
```

I found out that When I try to groupby, there was something wrong, but I don't know why:

```
large_depts = df[df['Department'].isin(Departments_top10)]\
                    [['Total', 'Department']]\
                    .groupby('Department')
print(large_depts)

<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000000000D1C0A08>
```

Here's the data: https://data.boston.gov/dataset/418983dc-7cae-42bb-88e4-d56f5adcf869/resource/31358fd1-849a-48e0-8285-e813f6efbdf1/download/employeeearningscy18full.csv

Comment: What is the format of your `Total` column? If it's string, `agg` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need call Department variable again. You can chage np.size to 'count' too. Try this code:

df[df['Department'].isin(Departments_top10)].Total.groupby('Department').agg([np.median, 'count'])

Comment: I tried your code, but it says: KeyError: 'Department'

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors going on in your code above.

1. Your `Total` column is not a numeric type (as you pointed out in the comments, it's a String). I'm assuming you can change (though permanent) your `Total` column and your code may work? I don't have access to your data so I can't fully check if your `groupby` functions are working.

   <strike>Here's code to change your string to list (as asked in the comments). Not sure if this is what you really want.</strike>

   `str2lst = lambda s: s.split(",")
   df['Total'] = [str2lst(i) for i in df['Total']]`

   **EDIT**: After looking at your DataFrame (and realizing that `Total` is a number and not a list), I uncovered several rows that contained the column names as values. Removing these as well as changing your string values to float type:

   ```
    df.drop([12556, 22124, 22123, 22122, 22121, 22125], inplace = True)
    str2float = lambda s: s.replace(',', '')
    df['Total'] = [float(str2float(i)) for i in df['Total']]
   ```

   Now running agg() exactly how you have it in the question will work. Here's my results:

   ```
                                             Total
   Department                         median       size
   BPS Facility Management            53183.315    668.0
   BPS Special Education              49875.830    831.0
   BPS Substitute Teachers/Nurs        6164.070    1196.0
   BPS Transportation                 20972.770    506.0
   Boston Cntr - Youth & Families     44492.625    584.0
   ```
2. In your last code entry, `groupby` ***has*** to have a method you're trying to group by with. Think about it intuitively, how are you grouping your variables? If I instructed you to group a set of cards together, you'd ask *how*? By color? Number? Suits? You told Python to group `Department`, but you didn't give it *how* you wanted it grouped. So Python returned a "...generic.DataFrameGroupBy object".

   Try doing `df...groupby('Department').count()` and you'll see `df` grouped by `Department`.

Comment: Hear is my data: https://data.boston.gov/dataset/418983dc-7cae-42bb-88e4-d56f5adcf869/resource/31358fd1-849a-48e0-8285-e813f6efbdf1/download/employeeearningscy18full.csv, I tried your way, but it won't work.

Comment: By the way, I tried another way to group: all_depts_sum = df[['Total', 'Department']].groupby('Department').agg(np.sum).sort_values('Total', ascending=False), it worked! Just the agg(np.median, np.size) won't work, and I don't know why...

Comment: I got your original group by to work. Nothing wrong with agg(), just with your data :)